# Significado de "correrse a" en Perú

Tags: significado, verbo-pronominal, perú

Leyendo una [noticia sobre la situación actual en Perú](https://www.elmundo.es/internacional/2019/10/01/5d92d64121efa02c2e8b459e.html), me encontré con este fragmento:

> Es mi deber como ciudadana, mujer, madre y vicepresidenta asumir este mandato. Lo más fácil habría sido renunciar. **No me corro a mis responsabilidades** por más difíciles que sean las circunstancias.

No acabo de comprender el significado de "correrse ***a*** [algo]" aquí. No parece encajar bien con ninguno de los [usos pronominales de ***correr***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ayuz2t0#JkYwc4h) recogidos en el DLE.

¿Qué significa el fragmento resaltado en negrita?

Comment: Creo que la preposición "de" sería más correcta. El significado sería: *No escapo a / reniego de mis responsabilidades*.

Comment: Ten en cuenta el [diccionario de americanismos](https://www.asale.org/recursos/diccionarios/damer) como fuente alterna cuando veas términos de este lado del charco, como te muestra en la respuesta@ukemi

Comment: Actually she says "No me corro de mis responsabilidades": Minute 7.05 at 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBMECVfU_5o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> #### [correr(se).](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=correr)
>
> **V.**
>
> 1. **intr. prnl.** ...
> 2. *Ni, Pe, Bo, Ch.* Eludir *alguien* un problema, una dificultad o una responsabilidad. pop.

Fuente: Diccionario de americanismos, RAE

El DAMER también muestra varios significados diferentes para esta palabra en Perú, pero el contexto deja claro que este es el significado para el ejemplo dado.

Comment: This sounds correct to me. I am from Chile and we use `correrse` in the same way, so it's lined with the definition in this answer that mention that is used in Nicaragua, Perú, Bolivia and Chile. Anyway, this is used in coloquial situations.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré otro [ejemplo](https://www.atv.pe/espectaculos/stephanie-valenzuela-se-corrio-a-las-preguntas-del-metiche-263804) de *correrse a* empleado en Perú:

> Stephanie Valenzuela se corrió a las preguntas del 'Metiche' ....  No quiso declarar sobre [el tema].

Parece ser que *correrse a las preguntas* quiere decir *evadir las preguntas*.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, como español, entiendo que

> "No me corro a mis responsabilidades"

se podría sustituir por

> "No huyo de mis responsabilidades"

pero seguro que alguien de Perú te puede responder con mas criterio.